# Sorting columns in JTable without affecting other columns

Tags: java, swing, split, jtable, tablerowsorter

Is there a way to make columns unrelated to each other in a `JTable` so that they may be sorted individually without affecting the other columns. An example of it might look like this.

[image: Columns sorted without relation to each other]

Comment: This actually makes no sense. The JTable will consider the rows in the table to be the same as a row in your database: releated information sorted this way. This would completely destroy the correlation there is between the data of the table. You could try by using seperate JTables close next to each other.

Comment: Wouldn't that essentially be a series of adjacent lists rather than a table?

Comment: @khelwood Yes it would be

Comment: It seems like a pretty silly thing to do but there's nothing stopping you from doing it by providing your own Model/TableRowSorter.

Comment: you can't break, to split row (doesn't matter if its came from model or view), this is possible with two (based on your printscreens) JTables in one JScrollPane (by using JPanel with GridBagLayout or easier, better with GridLayout)

Comment: those two JTables can must be based on two XxxTableModel, because (AFAIK) models event are shareable for both (or more) JTable views

Comment: @khelwood JList isn't sortable (methods implemented in API), it would be easier and more efficient to use JTable with one column like as JList

Comment: There are many ways to achieve this, and I can even think of a few good reasons to do it. However, this isn't a good question for SO because it's too broad. Try it yourself: hint, respond to the header click event and just rearrange your model data accordingly. If you get stuck, just ask for help with specific issues.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Would I be correct in saying that the header click event is handled under `javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter<M,I>`?

Comment: @mKorbel Sorry to comment but could you look at [Get column which fires RowSorterEvent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811380/get-column-which-fires-rowsorterevent). Normally I wouldn't ask this way but it has received 4 views 20 minutes after asking